# Counting States in the trim automaton for $L\circ L'$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, counting

**Preliminaries**. Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let our alphabet be $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, with **non-empty** languages $ L \subseteq \Sigma^n$ and $ L' \subseteq \Sigma^m$. We follow the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model) for **deterministic** finite-state automata except that we allow the state-transition function $\delta$ to be a partial function. In other words, an FSM has a finite number of states with transitions between them. We define the *depth* of a state $s$ as the length of the shortest path from the start state (at depth zero) to $s$.

A state $q$ is considered *accessible* if there is a path from the start state to $q$. A state $q$ is called *co-accessible* if there is a path from $q$ to a final state. Finally, an automaton is called *trim* if all its states are both accessible and co-accessible. This is defined [here](https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/%7Edeepakd/atc-common/straubing-weil-maat.pdf).

Consider the minimal trim finite-state automaton $A$ for the concatenation $L \circ L'$. We observe that this language is also finite.

**Question**: Can we conclude that the number of states in $A$ at level $n$ is 1?

**Argument**: All the strings in $L$ are in the same equivalence class for the Myhill-Nerode congruence for $L\circ L'$, since there is no distinguishing extension for any two strings in $L\in \Sigma^n$. All strings not in $L$ will land in the sink state, which is trimmed out of the minimal trim automaton.

Comment: Since we are dealing with nondeterministic finite automata, it is misleading to mention Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Comment: I just realized that you might mean the minimal *deterministic* trim automaton for $L\circ L'$. If that is the case, then the proof in my answer can be simplified by noting that there is unique state that represents the Myhill-Nerode equivalence class that is $L$ once the same claim is proved.

Comment: There can be multiple nonderministic trim automata of the minimal size for the same language.

Comment: Please clarify whether $A$ is supposed to be a deterministic automaton or a nonderministic automaton. In the referenced note, an automaton defaults to be nonderministic.

Comment: @JohnL.: I mean deterministic automata throughout.

Comment: @JohnL.: I've edited the question to reflect this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, automata are assumed deterministic and possibly incomplete in the question and this answer. A trim automaton is incomplete unless it is empty or it accepts all strings.

As your argument indicates, there must be exactly one state in $A$ at depth $n$. Here is a proof for the more general case **when $L'$ is a nonempty finite regular language** instead of a nonempty language $\subseteq\Sigma^m$.

###### A description of the minimum trim automaton

Any two minimum trim automata for the same language are isomorphic. Hence we use the phrase "the minimum trim automaton".

Given a nonempty regular language $R$, we can construct the minimum trim automaton for $R$ as follows. For each equivalence class $e$ of the Nerode congruence for $R$, let $q_e$ be a state that represents $e$. Let $o$ be the equivalence class that contains the empty string. The minimum trim automaton for $R$ is the $4$-tuple
$$(\{q_e\mid\text{ there exists } w\in e\text{ and } r\in R\text{ such that }r\text{ starts with }w\},\\
\delta,\\
q_o,\\
(\{q_e\mid\text{ there exists } w\in e\text{ such that }w\in R\}),$$
where $\delta(q_e, a)=q_{e'}$ for all $e, a, e'$ such that there exists $w\in e$ with $wa\in e'$. Note that $q_o$ is not trimmed out because $R$ is not empty.

###### A proof of the existence and uniqueness of a state of depth $n$

We can construct the minimum trim automaton $A$ for $R=L\circ L'$ as described above.

Note that $L\circ L'$ consists of every string that is a string in $L\in\Sigma^n$ followed by a string in $L'$. So $L$ is an equivalence class of the Nerode congruence for $L\circ L'$. Since $A$ is a trim automaton for $L\circ L'$, all paths from the initial state of length $n$ end at $q_L$. It is enough to prove that $q_L$ is of depth $n$.

Since $L$ and $L'$ are nonempty, there is a path of length $n$ that starts from the initial state and ends at $q_L$. The depth of $q_L$ is at most $n$.

Towards a contradiction, suppose the depth of $q_L$ is $<n$, i.e. there is a path $h$ of length $<n$ from the initial state to $q_L$. Since all paths of length $n$ from the initial state end at $q_L$ and all strings in $L\circ L'$ have length at least $n$ and $A$ is a trim automaton, we can extend $h$ until its length becomes $n$, at which time it must end at $q_L$. Since the original $h$ also end at $q_L$, we have found a cycle in $A$, which implies the language accepted by $A$ is infinite. However, $L\circ L'$ is finite. This contradiction completes our proof.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Let $L'=\emptyset$ and $n>1$.  Then $L \circ L' = \emptyset$, so its minimal automaton has no states at level $n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this counterexample. Is there a problem if we restrict the question to languages that are not empty?

Comment: I've added the restriction that the languages be non-empty.