# Counting States in the trim automaton for $(L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \ldots \cup L_p) \circ L'$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

**Preliminaries**. Let $n,m,p \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n,m,p > 1$. We allow that $p$
could be large but still bounded by a function of $n$: $p = O(2^n)$. Let our alphabet be $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, with
non-empty languages $ L_1,L_2,...L_p \subseteq \Sigma^n$ and $ L' \subseteq \Sigma^m$. The other preliminaries are the same as the [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159828/counting-states-in-the-trim-automaton-for-l-circ-l):

> We follow
> the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model)
> for deterministic finite-state automata except that we allow the state-transition function $\delta$
> to be a partial function. In other words, an FSM has a finite number of states with transitions between
> them. We define the *depth* of a state $s$ as the length of the shortest path from the start state (at depth zero) to $s$.
>
> A state $q$ is considered *accessible* if there is a path from the start state to $q$. A state $q$ is
> called *co-accessible* if there is a path from $q$ to a final state. Finally, an automaton is called *trim*
> if all its states are both accessible and co-accessible.
> This is defined [here](https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/%7Edeepakd/atc-common/straubing-weil-maat.pdf).

**Question 1**: Consider the minimal trim finite-state automaton $A$ for the language $(L_1 \cup L_2) \circ L'$. We observe
that this language is also finite.
Can we conclude that the number of states in $A$ at level $n$ is 1?

**Question 2**: Consider the minimal trim finite-state automaton $B$ for the language $(L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \ldots \cup L_p) \circ L'$. We observe
that this language is also finite.
Can we conclude that the number of states in $B$ at level $n$ is 1?

**Argument**: If we let $L = L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \ldots \cup L_p$, the argument is similar: All the strings in $L$ are in the same equivalence class for the Myhill-Nerode congruence
for $L \circ L'$, since there is no distinguishing extension for any two strings in $L \in \Sigma^n$.
All strings not in $L$ will land in the sink state, which is trimmed out of the minimal trim automaton. Could the [proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159843/1295) offered in the previous question work here as well?

**Question 3**: How does the number of states at level $n$ change if we drop the stipulation that these automata be trim and let $\delta$ be a total function?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I suggest you ask Question 3 separately, in a separate post.  I also suggest that you show your work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and yes.  This follows from the result in [your prior question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159828/755), letting $L = L_1 \cup L_2$ or $L = L_1 \cup \dots \cup L_p$.