# Counting States in the trim automaton for $\cup_{i=1}^{p} L_i \circ L'_i$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

**Preliminaries**. Let $n,m,i,j,p,c \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n,m,i,j,p,c \geq 1$.
Let our alphabet be $\{0,1\}$, with
non-empty languages $ L_i \subseteq \Sigma^n$ and $ L'_i \subseteq \Sigma^m$.
The other preliminaries are the same as a [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159828/counting-states-in-the-trim-automaton-for-l-circ-l):

> We follow
> the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model)
> for deterministic finite-state automata except that we allow the state-transition function $\delta$
> to be a partial function. In other words, an FSM has a finite number of states with transitions between
> them. We define the *depth* of a state $s$ as the length of the shortest path from the start state (at depth zero) to $s$.
>
> A state $q$ is considered *accessible* if there is a path from the start state to $q$. A state $q$ is
> called *co-accessible* if there is a path from $q$ to a final state. Finally, an automaton is called *trim*
> if all its states are both accessible and co-accessible.
> This is defined [here](https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/%7Edeepakd/atc-common/straubing-weil-maat.pdf).

**Question**: Consider the minimal trim deterministic
finite-state automaton $A$ for the language

$$\cup_{i=1}^{p} L_i \circ L'_i$$

We observe that this language is finite.
Can we conclude that the number of states in $A$ at level $n$ is $p$? We are given three additional constraints:

1. All of the $L'_i$ are mutually disjoint, so for $i \neq j$,
   we have $L'_i \cap L'_j = \emptyset$.
2. Same for the $L_i$: for $i \neq j$, $L_i \cap L_j = \emptyset$.
3. The upper limit $p$ is polynomially bounded by $n$:
   $p = O(n^c)$ for some fixed $c$.

**Argument**: By Myhill-Nerode, the only distinguishing extensions come from the
$L'_i$, and there are only $p$ mutually disjoint sets of those, so there are only $p$ states at level $n$ of the automaton. All strings not in any of the $L_i$ will land in the sink state, which is trimmed out of the minimal trim automaton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the number of states in $A$ at level $n$ is $p$, even without the 3rd constraint. The following is a proof.

---

Assume $A$ is constructed as in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159843/91753).

As observed in question, it is straightforward to verify that each $L_i$ is an equivalence class of the Nerode congruence for the given language $L=\cup_{i=1}^{p} L_i \circ L'_i$. Recall that for each equivalence class $e$, the label of any path from the initial state to state $q_e$ is in $e$. Since $A$ is a trim automaton for $L$, all paths from the initial state of length $n$ end at $q_{L_i}$ for some $i$.

It is enough to prove that $q_{L_i}$ is of depth $n$ for all $i$.

Fix an arbitrary $i$.

Let $f\in L_i$ and $g\in L_i'$. There is a path from the initial state to $q_{L_i}$ with label $f$ as well as a path from $q_{L_i}$ to an accept state with label $g$. The former path implies the depth of $q_{L_i}$ is at most $n$.

Towards a contradiction, suppose the depth of $q_{L_i}$ is $<n$, i.e. there is a path of length $<n$ from the initial state to $q_{L_i}$. Let $h$ be the label of this path.

Both $fg$ and $hg$ are in $L$ since each of them is the label of a path from the initial state to an accept state. The length of $fg$ is different from that of $hg$. However, all strings in $L$ are of the same length. This contradiction completes our proof.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!